# Coordinates of Cursor on floating canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am looking to get the x and y coordinates of the cursor in a canvas such that the coordinates depend on where the cursor is on the canvas rather than where it is on the screen.

Here is my current test code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root,width=300 ,height=300 ,background = 'gray')
canvas.pack()

def callback(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print(canvas.find_closest(x, y))


canvas.bind('<Motion>',mouseMove)
root.mainloop()
```

Now if for example i place my cursor on the top right of the canvas and the canvas is in the top right of my screen i get a value close to 0,0.
Now if i place my cursor on the same part of the canvas but with the canvas at the bottom of my screen i get a value of around 1000,700.
How do i make it so that it stays on 0,0 for my cursor at the top right no matter where the canvas is?

Comment: *"where the cursor is on the canvas"*: What gives `event.x, event.y`?

Comment: The code you posted does not have the behavior you say it does. For one, it calls `mouseMove` but there is no `mouseMove`. Assuming you meant `callback`, it still doesn't have that behavior. When I fix the obvious errors, the x/y that is computed in `callback` is correctly computed relative to the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the code you have posted is not the code you have been running as it does not produce the output you describe. On correction for errors an making an assuption on what output should look like I've come up with the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, background='gray')
canvas.pack()

def mouseMove(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print(x, y)

canvas.bind('<Motion>',mouseMove)
root.mainloop()
```

which is almost the same code you posted but returns the output you desire. Im running Python 3.6.5 under Windows 10.